# Setting form field label width and align checkbox to right

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I'm trying to set a width limit on a input label and at the same time align a styled check to the right.

The below image shows how it currently looks and how I'd like it to look:

[image]

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<a href='#' class='tooltip' title='tooltip text.'><img src='images/tooltip.png'></a>&nbsp;<b>This is my Text Label:</b></div>&nbsp; 

<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' title='checkbox' value="1"><div class="slider"></div></label>

<br/><input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput" size="40" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text here" value="" tabindex='1' disabled/></div><br/>
```

I've created a fiddle showing it here:
**https://jsfiddle.net/bywgqnrg/1/**

Can anyone advise the best way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, I added a `fieldwrap` to wrap the whole content and sets a fixed width and floated the switch to right check the code below:

```css
.switch { position:relative; display:inline-block; width:53px; height:19px } 
.switch input { display:none } 
.slider { position:absolute; cursor:pointer; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background-color:#ccc; -webkit-transition:.4s; transition:.4s } 
.slider:before { position:absolute; content:""; height:11px; width:19px; left:4px; bottom:4px; background-color:#fff; -webkit-transition:.4s; transition:.4s } 
input:checked+.slider { background-color:#008c00 } input:focus+.slider { box-shadow:0 0 1px #2196F3 } 
input:checked+.slider:before { -webkit-transform:translateX(26px); -ms-transform:translateX(26px); transform:translateX(26px) } 

input, select, textarea {border: 1px solid #A0A0A0; background: #FFF; padding: 3px 4px; color: #222; margin: 2px 5px 2px 0px; }
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus { outline: none;}


.fieldwrap { width : 320px; overflow : hidden; }
.fieldwrap .switch {float : right;}
```

```html
 <div class="fieldwrap">
     <a href='#' class='tooltip' title='tooltip text.'><img src='images/tooltip.png'></a>&nbsp;<b>This is my Text Label:</b>&nbsp; 

    <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' title='checkbox' value="1"><div class="slider"></div></label>
 <div><input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput" size="40" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text here" value="" tabindex='1' disabled/></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Fantastic - that does exactly what I'm looking for.. thanks :)